# Testing a web based application on Iphone

Tags: iphone, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to test a web site on the iPhone without an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510278/is-there-a-way-to-test-a-web-site-on-the-iphone-without-an-iphone)

I have been looking for a way to penetration test an Iphone based web application. XCode has got the option to test native applications, but how would I test a web based application?

It would be great if you guys suggest the steps and/or the application used for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Safari app in the iOS Simulator for mac bundled with XCode or just use regular safari?